# clear iframe content (including it's JS global scope)

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, scope

I'm creating an iframe dynamically like this:

```js
let code = "<html><head><title> hello world <\/title><\/head><body><h1> hello world <\/h1><script>const h1 = document.querySelector('h1'); h1.style.color = 'red'<\/script><\/body><\/html>"

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.body.appendChild(iframe)

const content = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
content.open()
content.write(code)
content.close()
```

then later I change it's contents like this:

```js
code = "<html><head><title> bye world <\/title><\/head><body><h1> bye world <\/h1><script>const h1 = document.querySelector('h1'); h1.style.color = 'red'<\/script><\/body><\/html>"
content.open()
content.write(code)
content.close()
```

but I get the following error: `SyntaxError: redeclaration of const h1` because of the JavaScript being injected into the iframe.

is there someway to clear the global variable scope within the iframe before i write new code to it? I've tried `iframe.contentWindow.location.replace('about:blank')` as well as `iframe.src = 'about:blank'` but this doesn't clear it's internal JS variable scope. (I get the same error)

I realize I could trash the entire iframe and make a new one, but I'm going to be replacing the code a couple of times a second and I'm hoping for a less costly approach to update it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, because I'm trying to get around a situation where mobile browsers are asking for mic permissions once for every iframe. So I wanted to just replace the content of the frame, but ran into the same SyntaxError: redeclaration.

Comment: @nforss dang, i hadn't thought of that, but in my use case i'm also going to likely hit that same issue (as i do plan on using APIs that now require explicit user permissions)... i really do hope there's a way around this :(

Comment: See [Iframe document write doesn't update JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76724943/478018) for some solutions.