# Iframe document write doesn't update JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here's a basic HTML editor:

```css
textarea,
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<iframe></iframe>
```

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

function preview() {
  var iframeDoc = document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument;
  iframeDoc.open();
  iframeDoc.write(textarea.value);
  iframeDoc.close();
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', preview);
```

[**DEMO**](https://labground.github.io/iframe-document-write-doesn%27t-update-javascript.html)

It updates the HTML and CSS you put in the `textarea`, but you can't use JavaScript `const` or `let` variables as it throws the following syntax error as soon as you edit the inserted code:

`Identifier * has already been declared`

To see what I mean, insert the following sample code in the `textarea`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sample Code</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <script>
    const p = document.querySelector('p');
    p.style.color = 'blue';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now change `Hello!` to `Hello, world!`, or `blue` to `red`.

What's the solution so the user can keep editing the code without getting that error?

### Update

Inspired by [svarlitskiy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76742291/478018), I finally decided to replace the `iframe` with a newly-created one:

```
function preview() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.querySelector('iframe').replaceWith(iframe);
  var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
  iframeDoc.write(textarea.value);
  iframeDoc.close();
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem!  A quick search gives me [similar things people have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546174/clear-iframe-content-including-its-js-global-scope) but no real solution. Maybe try deleting and recreating the `<iframe>` each time?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, there are two main ways to do this: using the `srcdoc` attribute ([@Kaiido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724943/iframe-document-write-doesnt-update-javascript/76726073#76726073)) or using a blob URL. In this answer,  I will explain what these options are and how they differ. I will also give you a code example of how to use the blob URL option.

### Using srcdoc

The `srcdoc` attribute lets you write the HTML content of the iframe as a string. This is easy and simple, but it has some problems:

•  Some old browsers do not support the `srcdoc` attribute, so you may need to provide a fallback using the src attribute.

•  The HTML content may contain malicious scripts or links that could compromise the security of your main document. You may need to sanitize or escape the HTML content before assigning it to the `srcdoc` attribute.

So if you don't mind such problems, you might not need this answer because using a `blob` URL is more complex and indirect than using `srcdoc`.

### Using blob URL

The blob URL method involves creating a new blob object from the HTML content, and then assigning its URL to the `src` attribute of the iframe. This method can avoid some compatibility and security issues:

•  The blob URL is supported by most browsers that support the `src` attribute, so you do not need to worry about fallbacks.

•  The blob URL is separate from the main document and has its own origin and permissions, so it cannot access or modify anything in your main document.

### Example:

Here is a code example of how to use the blob URL method. I have used a `debounce` function to avoid updating the iframe too often, which could cause flickering. You can find more information about the `debounce` function [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

```
function preview() {
  var blob = new Blob([textarea.value], { type: "text/html" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  iframe.onload = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
  iframe.src = url;
}


var debounceTimer;

function debounce(func, delay) {
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(func, delay);
  };
}

var debouncedPreview = debounce(preview, 300);

textarea.addEventListener("input", debouncedPreview);
```

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
var debounceTimer;

function debounce(func, delay) {
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(func, delay);
  };
}

function preview() {
  var blob = new Blob([textarea.value], { type: "text/html" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  iframe.onload = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
  iframe.src = url;
}

var debouncedPreview = debounce(preview, 300);

textarea.addEventListener("input", debouncedPreview);
```

```css
textarea,
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

In summary, both the `srcdoc` and the blob URL methods can be used to create a live preview of HTML content in an iframe. The `srcdoc` method is simpler but less compatible and secure, while the blob URL method is more complex but more compatible and secure. I prefer the blob URL method because it avoids some potential problems with old browsers and malicious content, but you may choose the method that suits your needs and preferences.

Comment: Using `srcdoc`: As I already mentioned, it causes two other problems: 1) The user can't try creating [destination anchors within a page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page) or work with the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector. 2) I want a real-time HTML editor, but it causes a delay and the whole `iframe` content flickers on each `input` event, which is really annoying, especially on larger HTML documents.

Comment: Using `blob` URL: There are two problems with this approach: 1) According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static#memory_management), each time you call `createObjectURL()`, a new object URL is created. Each of these must be released by calling `URL.revokeObjectURL()` for optimal performance and memory usage. 2) It has the same flickering problem as using `srcdoc`.

Comment: @Mori, thank you for your comments. I understand your concerns and I appreciate your feedback. I agree that both options have some drawbacks, such as needing to create and revoke object URLs or causing flickering in the iframe. You are right that using the `URL.revokeObjectURL()` method is a good practice to avoid memory leaks, and I thank you for suggesting it. I did not include it in my answer because I thought it was obvious, but maybe I should have mentioned it for clarity. I have updated my answer accordingly.  : )

Comment: @Mori, Debouncing I mentioned in my answer is one possible solution to avoid flickering. And there are also some possible solutions for the flickering problem, such as hiding, cloning, or caching the iframe.

Comment: **A blob:URL is also same-origin!** If you want the `srcdoc` to be cross domain you can use the `sandbox` attribute. Using a blob: URL implies more I/O work. And browser support for `srcdoc` is like ten years ago. Browser support for blob: URLs as `<iframe>`'s src is about the same.

Answer (score 4):

Set your iframe's `srcdoc` instead of reopening its `Document`:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'),
  iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

function preview() {
  iframe.srcdoc = textarea.value;
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', preview);
```

```css
textarea,
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it causes two other problems: 1) The user can't try creating [destination anchors within a page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page) or work with the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector. 2) It causes a delay and the `iframe` blinks on each `input` event, which is really annoying, especially on larger HTML documents.

Comment: Those two issues would have held with document.write too.

Comment: You could defer the rendering of the iframe by using setTimeout to deal with the blink

Comment: `function preview() {
  iframe.src = 'about:blank';
  iframe.onload = function() {
    iframe.contentDocument?.write(textarea.value);
  };
}` is just the same as `iframe.srcdoc = textarea.value` but in a more complicated and slower way, more prone to the "blink" you were talking about, since the browser will wait for the *about:blank* page to render before setting its content. As for why aEL didn't work I have no idea, you probably [messed up somewhere](https://jsfiddle.net/yd19aomb/) but you don't show and it doesn't seem related to the initial question.

Comment: That's a good point. So you may use something like debounce. - @svarlitskiy

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to input partial HTML and still render the page in the iframe without the blink.

**HTML**

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<iframe id="result"></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```css
textarea,
iframe {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

**JS**

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('input');
let iframe = document.getElementById('result');

function preview() {
    const elem = document.createElement("iframe");
    const dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString( textarea.value, 'text/html' );
    
    elem.id = iframe.id
    iframe.replaceWith( elem );
    iframe = elem;
    
    const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow?.document;
    if ( !iframeDoc ) return null;
    iframeDoc.open();
    iframeDoc.write( dom.documentElement.outerHTML );
    iframeDoc.close();
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', preview);
```

Comment: Your solution works, but wouldn't the following be simpler? `function preview() {const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); document.querySelector('iframe').replaceWith(iframe); iframe.contentDocument.write(textarea.value);}`

Comment: Sure you could do it that way but then your using browser resources to find the iframe each time the method is executed. But the way I wrote the code, I keep a reference to the new iframe and therefore do not need to query for it each time an input event is received. Also the reason I transfer the id of the iframe is in case other code needs to find the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```
function preview() {
  document.querySelector('iframe').outerHTML = '<iframe></iframe>';
  var iframeDoc = document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument;
  iframeDoc.write(textarea.value);
  iframeDoc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to un-declare variables in JS or remove them from a document's scope. I'd suggest dynamically recreating an `iframe` element on each `input` event. Something like this:

```js
// index.js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

function preview() {
  const container = document.getElementById("iframe-container");
  const existing = document.querySelector("iframe");

  if (existing) existing.remove();

  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  container?.appendChild(iframe);
  const iframeDoc = iframe?.contentDocument;

  iframeDoc?.open();
  iframeDoc?.write(textarea?.value ?? "");
  iframeDoc?.close();
}

textarea?.addEventListener("input", preview);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="iframe-container">
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: _"there is no way to un-declare variables in JS"_- there _kinda_ is: [the `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Top-level `var` properties exist as `global` properties, so `delete foo` is the same as `delete window.foo` - and so _should_ remove a `var` from scope (though not `let` or `const` as those aren't promoted to global properties).

Comment: I don't understand why you have used the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator. And wouldn't it be simpler to put your idea like this? `function preview() {document.querySelector('iframe').remove(); const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); document.body.appendChild(iframe); iframe.contentDocument.write(textarea.value);}`

Comment: @Mori without the optional chaining, you'd be making assumptions that the elements exist when that code is executed. Try writing my example in Typescript (like I did) and you'll get warnings that `'element' is possibly 'null'`. You'll get the same for your `document.querySelector('iframe').remove();` suggestion which I could have slightly simplified by writing `document.querySelector('iframe')?.remove();` (notice the optional chain).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is due to the fact that every time you call **iframeDoc.write(textarea.value)**, it completely recreates the content of the iframe, including its JavaScript context. This means that when you modify the content in the textarea, the new JavaScript code conflicts with the previously declared variables, causing the "Identifier has already been declared" error.

To overcome this issue and allow the user to keep editing the code without getting that error, you can use the **document.createElement** method to create new script elements and add them to the iframe document's head. This way, you won't be overwriting the entire iframe content, and the JavaScript context will be preserved.

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea'),
  iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

function preview() {
  var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
  iframeDoc.open();
  iframeDoc.write(textarea.value);
  iframeDoc.close();

  // Extract and execute script tags in the iframe separately
  var scriptElements = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for (var i = 0; i < scriptElements.length; i++) {
    eval(scriptElements[i].text);
  }
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', preview);
textarea,
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

With this approach, when you update the content in the textarea, it will only update the HTML and CSS parts in the iframe using **iframeDoc.write()**. The JavaScript code inside the iframe will be extracted and executed separately using **eval()** on the script tags, allowing the user to keep editing the code without encountering the "Identifier has already been declared" error.

Comment: Would you mind providing a working demo?

Comment: This answer will fail when you try to access variables declared in two (or more) different `<script/>` blocks, also the `Identifier xx has already been declared` error will still be thrown, nice try though